# Hibernate-JPA: Selection items that are to be returned in the query result

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Below is given a snippet of code from a [web article](https://www.boraji.com/hibernate-5-criteria-query-example) that describes Hibernate usage of the JPA Criteria API.  I have verified that the code works, without any issues.  My question pertains to the statement `criteriaQuery.multiselect(empRoot, deptRoot);`

If the above-mentioned method had been invoked in the "fluent-style", I would have no questions.  However, it is obvious that this method has a side effect because if I try to comment it out (since the result is not stored in any variable), a real-time exception is raised.

---

**So what exactly happens “under the hood” when the** `criteriaQuery.multiselect(...)` **method is invoked?**

```
package com.boraji.tutorial.hibernate;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.criteria.*;

import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;

import com.boraji.tutorial.hibernate.entity.Department;
import com.boraji.tutorial.hibernate.entity.Employee;

public class CriteriaQueryExample6 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Transaction transaction = null;
      try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession()) {
         transaction = session.beginTransaction();

         CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

         // Using FROM and JOIN
         CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);
         Root<Employee> empRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Employee.class);
         Root<Department> deptRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Department.class);
         criteriaQuery.multiselect(empRoot, deptRoot);
         criteriaQuery.where(builder.equal(empRoot.get("department"), deptRoot.get("id")));

         Query<Object[]> query=session.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
         List<Object[]> list=query.getResultList();
         for (Object[] objects : list) {
            Employee employee=(Employee)objects[0];
            Department department=(Department)objects[1];
            System.out.println("EMP NAME="+employee.getName()+"\t DEPT NAME="+department.getName());
         }
         transaction.commit();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         if (transaction != null) {
            transaction.rollback();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply tells JPA that you want to do a projection.

In your case Employee, Department.

So that the result will contain an Employee entity in the first row and a Department entity in the second row.